# Jco.createClient is undefined for the type Jco

Tags: java, eclipse, jco, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to connect to SAP server using java code, which written in eclipse.
here I am using this code.......

```
JCO.Client mConnection;      /*getting compilation error*/
JCO.Repository mRepository;  /*getting compilation error*/

Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "********");
connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR,  "**");
connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "***");                   

connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER,   "*****");
connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "*****");
connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG,   "en");
createDestinationDataFile("ABAP_AS_WITHOUT_POOLs", connectProperties);
mConnection = JCo.createClient(connectProperties);  /*getting compilation error */
```

Also I have added sapjco3.jar in my project. 
I don't know why I am getting compilation error...

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: mConnection = JCo.createClient(connectProperties);  error: createClient(connectProperties)  is undefined for the type JCo

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses the deprecated JCo release 2.x, which is not supported anymore by SAP for several years now.

In JCo 2.x one API was `JCO.createClient(...)` and not `JCo.createClient(...)`.

Class `JCo` from package `com.sap.conn.jco` belongs to the JCo 3.0 API but does not have a method `createClient()`.
And classes `JCO.Client` and `JCO.Repository` also do not exist in JCo 3.0 anymore.

The JCo API changed completely from version 2 to 3.

I recommend not to work with de-supported software any longer, but to migrate your Java sources from using JCo release 2.x to 3.0 now.
Or if just starting with developing your first JCo application, don't think about JCo 2.x anymore but directly use and learn with JCo 3.0 instead.

Comment: JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("**********");  
            System.out.println("Attributes:");
            System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());                                                  Can you suggest me how to find destination/ what should I put in .getDestination() ??

Comment: Using above code I am able to verify whether connection is established or not, just don't have idea of what's the value of destination.

Comment: You have to put the name of your destination there ("YourDestName"). If using the default JCo infrastructure implementations, then you need to create a property text file named `YourDestName.jcoDestination` in the current working directory. This file must contain all your logon parameters like `jco.client.ashost=hostname.in.your.domain`. Valid and required properties are described in the JavaDoc of interface `com.sap.conn.jco.ext.DestinationDataProvider`.